# XSL combining multiple node trees into HTML output

Tags: xml, xslt

Quick note: I am restricted to XSL 1.0, so bear that in mind when reading the question.

I have a set of XML, which looks like the following:

```xml
<TOP_LEVEL>
    <ele1 />
    <ele2 />
    <ele3 />
    <ele4 />
    <ele5 />
    .
    .
    .
</TOP_LEVEL>
```

Which is being transformed with the following transformation:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/TOP_LEVEL">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <table style="background-color:green;">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Business Name</th>
                    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="ele1" /></td>
                    <th>Score</th>
                    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="ele2" /></td>
                </tr>
                .
                .
                .
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Which is all fine and good, and that works fine. However, I have a new requirement.

This XML is returned from an external service, and it turns out that I will not only have multiple copies of it (older / newer information, etc), but that I may have to amalgamate some of those together for display, and I'm not sure how best to achieve that.

Currently, I'm expecting I will have:

```xml
<TOP_TOP_LEVEL>
    <TOP_LEVEL>
        <ele1 />
        <ele2 />
        <ele3 />
        <ele4 />
        <ele5 />
        .
        .
        .
    </TOP_LEVEL>
    <TOP_LEVEL>
        <ele1 />
        <ele2 />
        <ele3 />
        <ele4 />
        <ele5 />
        .
        .
        .
    </TOP_LEVEL>
    <TOP_LEVEL>
        <ele1 />
        <ele2 />
        <ele3 />
        <ele4 />
        <ele5 />
        .
        .
        .
    </TOP_LEVEL>
    <TOP_LEVEL>
        <ele1 />
        <ele2 />
        <ele3 />
        <ele4 />
        <ele5 />
        .
        .
        .
        </TOP_LEVEL>
</TOP_TOP_LEVEL>
```

But then, how do I perform the translation? I currently plan on doing it something like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/TOP_TOP_LEVEL">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <table style="background-color:green;">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
                <col style="width:25%" />
            </colgroup>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Business Name</th>
                    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="child::nodes()/ele1" /></td>
                    <th>Score</th>
                    <td><xsl:apply-templates select="child::nodes()/ele2" /></td>
                </tr>
                .
                .
                .
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

That is, putting `child::nodes()` in every `apply-templates` element, but is there a neater way than that? This should work because, while the possible set of nodes that can be children of `TOP_LEVEL` is the same, each of the four actually represent four different things, so they should all different (or mostly different) children.

Also, while I expect that the list of non-empty notes in `TOP_LEVEL[1]` will be mostly different to the list of non-empty nodes in `TOP_LEVEL[2]`, some elements may be populated in more than one tree (e.g. `TOP_LEVEL[1]/randomElement99` and `TOP_LEVEL[2]/randomElement99` may both have a value of `BLURGH`, or even totally different values). At this stage, I'd be happy to just take the value of the element in `TOP_LEVEL[1]` if there's duplicate content, but as far as I know, the code above will result in them being concatenated together, which is less than ideal.

The expected output is pretty straightforward - it's just a four-column table, with values pulled from the XML and given slightly more descriptive names.

If it's relevant, this transformation is being done with Xalan 2.7.1, on Java 7.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: The "pretty straightforward" expected output is not really clear to me. Please provide a minimal, but specific example that covers all edge cases (XML and concrete output for that XML). For starters, it looks like you actually want a multi-row table. Putting multiple values into a single cell is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did solve this, but without using XSL.

Instead, I just performed some pre-processing in Java, which

1. Created a new document.
2. Iterated through the child elements in each document I had to merge.
3. Added a clone of that element to this new document, if they weren't already present.

Simple. That said, I would like to know if I could have done this in XSL, so I won't accept my own answer just yet.